# PHP Memory Leak in class structure

Tags: php, oop, memory-leaks, iterator

hoping someone can help me out with this, bit stumped.

So doing some mucking about with images and polygons, but getting a weird memory leak.

So I have a wrapper class called canvas which just holds my image resource, another called polygon which is used to manage and manipulate another class called vertices which is just a container for an array of x and y coordinators.

So pretty straight forward.

I noticed that I was getting a memory outage error tracked it down to a method called getPoly on the canvas class, which returns an instance of polygon, which on construct sets the vertices class.

If you use this method, even after unsettling the variable the memory for the image resource is not returned, but it is if you create an instance of Polygon normally with the new keyword and unset it thats fine.

The canvas class also has another method called destroy which:

```
imagedestroy($this->canvas);
```

So using this:

```
$img  = new Image_Canvas($width, $height);
$poly = $img->getPoly();
$img->destroy();
//Memory not returned
```

But

```
$img  = new Image_Canvas($width, $height);
$poly = new Image_Polygon($width, $height)
$img->destroy();
//Memory is returned

public function getPoly($width= null, $height =null)
{
     if(!is_int($width) || !is_int($height))
     {
        return new Image_Polygon($this->width, $this->height);
     }
     else
     {
        return new Image_Polygon($width, $height);
     }
}
```

Now whats weird is its not actually a image resource issue, the issue seems to come from the fact that the vertices class implements Iterator, if Vertices doesn't implement Iterator then the memory is returned normally either way. It would be preferable for Vertices to implement Iterator for the helpful looping assistance.

Any help or previous experience with this would be great.

Comment: Could you please provide the Image_Polygon class source code? Otherwise it's hard to tell what's the issue.

Comment: the issue, I suspect is with the Vertices Class, as if it doesnt impliment iterator then there is no memory leak.

Comment: ok, then you could provide Vertices class source code, maybe we will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am a moron and had an obvious bug assigning large variables to a class property in my code which was causing the memory leak.

Good programming 0, noobery 1